# Ruby: combining methods into 1 line

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects, and I want to take one of the methods to return it into 1 single line.

here is my array

```
def set
        @seconds = Counter.new('Seconds')
        @minutes = Counter.new('Minutes')
        @hours = Counter.new('Hours')

        @time = [@seconds, @minutes, @hours]
    end
```

and here is the method I'm trying to print in the Counter class

```
    def count
        @counts
    end
```

Here's my attempt

```
    def read
        reverse = @time.reverse
        @time.each do |t|
            return '%02d' %t.count.to_s.join(":")
        end
    end
```

(I also want them to be in 00, 01 formats, hence the '%02d')

.join doesn't seem to work (I'm guessing it works with arrays but not methods of an array?

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close!

You need to do the joining outside of your loop, and use [`collect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) instead of `each`. Here is an irb session that should help you figure things out:

```
>> seconds = 35
>> minutes = 9
>> hours = 11
>> time = [seconds, minutes, hours]
>> time.reverse.collect{|t| "%02d" % t}.join(":")
=> "11:09:35"
```

The idea is that `collect` (called `map` in other languages) applies the stringification operation to each array element, turning

```
[11, 9, 35]
```

into

```
["11", "09", "35"]
```

then you can do the join on this array.

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given this `Counter` class and some instances:

```
class Counter
  attr_accessor :count

  def initialize(name, count: 0)
    @name = name
    @count = count
  end
end

@seconds = Counter.new('Seconds', count: 52)
@minutes = Counter.new('Minutes', count: 30)
@hours = Counter.new('Hours', count: 11)

@time = [@seconds, @minutes, @hours]
```

You can extract the `count` values in hour / minute / second order via:

```
@time.reverse.map(&:count)
#=> [11, 30, 52]
```

This array can be passed (in its entirety) to [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-25) to produce a `HH:MM:SS` string:

```
'%02d:%02d:%02d' % @time.reverse.map(&:count)
#=> "11:30:52"
```

---

#### Some improvements

You can get rid of `reverse` by changing the order of your `@time` array:

```
@time = [@hours, @minutes, @seconds]

'%02d:%02d:%02d' % @time.map(&:count)
#=> "11:30:52"
```

This can be simplified further by providing a `to_i` method:

```
class Counter
  # ...

  def to_i
    @count
  end
end

# ...

@time = [@hours, @minutes, @seconds]

'%02d:%02d:%02d' % @time
#=> "11:30:52"
```

The above works because `%` tries to call `to_i` when specifying an integer format.